# How to force conda to link to system libraries?

Tags: jenkins, linker, conda, lib

When compiling some of our software with Jenkins, I ran into a problem. When compiling the software by hand on the machine Jenkins runs on (under a different user), this ldd for the executable shows (among other):

```
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
```

When compiling with Jenkins on the same machine via a build job, this changes to

```
libz.so.1 => /opt/<projectName>/root/bin/./../../lib/libz.so.1
```

And I am not sure why. The output for both my user and the jenkins user for

```
ldconfig -v 2>/dev/null | grep -v ^$'\t'
```

Is exactly the same, with no mention of the path linked in the executable compiled via Jenkins.

I tried

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=
```

in the build.sh of the project to override some other values that might be set there, but it didn't change anything.

How can I force conda/jenkins to disregard the conda libraries and use the system libraries instead?